# How to efficiently shorten a list from a very large one?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I am facing an efficiency issue with my code where I am trying to collapse a very long list into a smaller more workable list.

I am getting data from sql that looks something like this:

```
[a,1,2,3,4,5,6....]
[b,1,2,3,4,5,6....]
[b,1,2,3,4,5,6....]
[b,1,2,3,4,5,6....]
[c,1,2,3,4,5,6....]
[c,1,2,3,4,5,6....]
```

And I turn it into:

```
[a,b,c] -> 
[[a,1,2,...]]
[[b,1,2,...],[b,1,2,...],[b,1,2,...]]
[[c,1,2,...],[c,1,2,...]]
```

Here is the code I am running to generate this.

```
master = []
for x in range(0, len(unique_ids)):
    master.append([])
    z=0;
    for y in range(0,len(mysql_return)):
        if(unique_ids[x] == list(mysql_return[y])[0]):
            master[x].append(list(mysql_return[y]))
```

The issue is this really degrades exponentially as the replies get into the 100's of Ks. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: is your input a list of lists?

Comment: I have 2 inputs to the loop, the list original list and a list of unique ids (first element of the lists, unique sorted..) and the output is list of lists.

Comment: You shouldn't import your whole database into a list (it loads in RAM)... Try to use generators when possible.

Comment: Do you really need to call `list(mysql_return[y])` instead of using `mysql_return[y]` as -is, and if so, you *really* don't need to call it twice.

Comment: Oh, I am not importing the entiredb, just doing some joins and pulling 1 hour of data at a time, but sometimes the number of rows can get out of hand.

Comment: The original data is list of tuples.

Comment: Don't use python 2.+, it is going to be discontinued soon.

Comment: I am on 2.7.6 thats the only repo I have available to me at the moment in the company I am on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

first = itemgetter(0)

items = [['a', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         ['b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         ['b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         ['b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         ['c', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         ['c', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]

for k,v in groupby(items, key=first):
    print(list(v))

[['a', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
[['b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
[['c', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ['c', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Where `items` is your list of lists.

Additionally you can store it in a dictionary

```
d = {}

for k,v in groupby(items, key=first):
    d[k] = list(v)

{'a': [['a', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
 'b': [['b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       ['b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       ['b', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],
 'c': [['c', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
       ['c', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]}
```

**Caveat: Data must be pre-sorted to begin with**

```
sorted(items, key=first)
```

Comment: Data will be sorted. I think there is some confusion here. I am trying to build the list of lists, it doesnt exist at the moment. Only the original exists.

Comment: yes I updated the answer to show what `items` looks like

Comment: you can build a list like that `[list(v) for k,v in groupby(items, key=first)]` This will build your list of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Nohting in your original code looks like it should exhibit any kind of exponential slowdown. `append` is an (amortized) O(1) operation, only requiring periodic expansion of the underlying array. That said, I would make few changes:

1. Use `mysql_return[y]` as-is, without creating a new list. If you *do* need a list instead of the original tuple for some reason, you don't need to create the list twice.
2. The only reason you use `x` is for read-only access to `unique_ids`; just iterate over the values directly. You don't need it to index `master`; you always want to append to the last element of `master`, which you can refer to with `master[-1]`.
3. The same goes for `y`; you only use it for read-only access to `mysql_return`.

---

```
master = []
for unique_id in unique_ids:
    master.append([])
    for sql in mysql_return:
        sql = list(sql)  # Possibly unnecessary
        if unique_id == sql[0]:
            master[-1].append(sql)
```

In fact, the entire inner loop can be replaced with a single list comprehension, with the resulting list appended to `master` after the fact.

```
master = []
for unique_id in unique_ids:
    master.append([list(x) for x in mysql_return if x[0] == unique_id])
```

And the remaining loop can *also* be replaced by a list comprehension.

```
master = [[list(x) for x in mysql_return if x[0] == unique_id] for unique_id in unique_ids]
```

Comment: As the length of list grows, I would iterate through more and more elements. It would get away from me

Comment: That's a problem with having a large list, regardless of how the list gets built. You aren't iterating over `master` while building it.